# Android Market/Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I had uploaded my app on google play yesterday, today if I search for my app's title in google play, my app appears after 80 to 100 apps?? 
Why is it so, any suggestions ???

Regards

Comment: it is possible that the name you gave to ur app can be common and app appearing in the market is shown by default according to their tag.try to give uniqueness to ur app and than try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of your app name, rating, #downloads. 
1. Make sure your name is not used by others or at least not too often
2. Make sure you receive as much stars / ratings as possible (ask users to rate inapp). The better/more rankings you app has the more its likely that your app will be displayed first
3. The downloadcounter also affects the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the name you gave to ur app can be common and app appearing in the market is shown by default according to their tag.try to give uniqueness to ur app and than try.It also depend on the number of times downloaded by users,likes,comments made on them,etc,etc... As the rates of your app increases it will automatically be up in chart.

Answer (score 0):

the ratings are based on popularity, no of hits etc. You should also try to promote your app.
The documentation talks about it.

> Preparing promotional materials.
>
> To fully leverage the marketing and publicity capabilities of Google
>   Play, you need to create promotional materials for your application,
>   such as screenshots, videos, graphics, and promotional text.

also check out :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058297/how-to-promote-android-app

and [this](http://www.androidtapp.com/tag/how-to-promote-your-android-apps/)

Comment: when I search the project name or package name every thing went perfect, but when I search the app's title things are not working !!!

Comment: as i said so there may be lots of apps having the same name.try to give uniqueness to ur app

Comment: it also takes some time. Apparently, Google Play puts older apps in front of newer `un-featured apps`